# How to save command in variable and print translated command before execution without bash -x

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

Using bash script function with a following command, looking for a way to print command for before execution for logging purposes without using bash -x, is that possible ? Problematic part is a last command.

```
helm upgrade $2 chart --install --wait --timeout $3 $debug "${@:4}"
```

Would like to print a following:

```
helm upgrade mypod chart --install --wait --timeout 600s --set key=value
```

Comment: What's wrong with bash -x ?

Comment: `echo helm upgrade $2 chart --install --wait --timeout $3 $debug "${@:4}"; helm upgrade $2 chart --install --wait --timeout $3 $debug "${@:4}"`. Just put echo in front of the command.

Comment: Thanks @jordanm for checking this, this script is part of a huge build script, don't want to get logs from everything. Think that basic echo will work for me, annoying part is to use the same line twice, didn't found a way to use variable for this.

Comment: You could make a function and store the whole command in array. `print_and_run() { echo "$@"; "$@"; }; cmd=(helm upgrade "$2" chart ....); print_and_run "${cmd[@]}"`

Comment: @jordanm, you don't even need the `cmd` array: `print_and_run help upgrade ...` will suffice. Hello, btw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just turning debug on and off?

```
set -x
helm upgrade $2 chart --install --wait --timeout $3 $debug "${@:4}"
set +x
other commands...
```